# Unzipping Zip files having a .done file in unix

Tags: bash, unix, unzip

**Problem statement:** I want to unzip files from a folder like /home/a/zip_input where there will be 2 zip files like: 
/home/a/zip_input
        a_EOD-20121129.zip
        b_EOD-20121129.zip

Also there will be 1 corresponding .done file for each each zip(basically once the zip is completely copied a .done file is created)
like: 
a_EOD-20121129.zip.done
b_EOD-20121129.zip.done

I am trying to write a script to unzip the files which are having a corresponding .done file, and move the file to a location /home/b/file_input. After the file is moved compeltely I want to create a file with .done ext. For eample:
each zip is having one xml file like a_EOD-20121129.xml/b_EOD-20121129.xml

so the output folder will have something like:

a_EOD-20121129.xml
a_EOD-20121129.xml.done 
b_EOD-20121129.xml
b_EOD-20121129.xml.done

**What I have tried Till now:**

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.zip" -type f)
do
    unzip $file -d /home/b/file_input
    rm $file    
done
```

Which unzips a.zip/b.zip and creates the xml files.

**Issue I am facing -**

1. How to make the condition in script that only picks files having a corresponding .done file?
2. How to create a corresponding .done file after the file is unzipped and moved.(have to take the file name and create a file with same name appending .done)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script(Not tested):

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.zip" -type f)
    do
      if [ -f $file".done" ];    then         #test if there is a done file for that zip
          unzip $file -d /home/b/file_input
          for filezip in `unzip -l $file | awk '/.xml$/{print $NF}'`; do  #creates the .done files for each file inside the zip
             touch /home/b/file_input/$filezip".done"
          done
          rm $file    
      fi
    done
```

Comment: thanks. which command is creating the .done file ? as logically it should extract the filename and append .done right ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. `touch /home/b/file_input/$filezip".done"` is the command that creates the ".done" file for each extracted file.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's working for craeting a .done file for the etracted file but along with that it's creating a bunch of unwanted .done files like Date.done, file.done, Archive:.done, Time.done etc, which should not have. could you give any inputs ?

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfectly fine.Thank you very much for your time. so I am just curious, mey be bacause I am very new to Unix. how did the above issue got resolved with `unzip -l $file | awk '/.xml$/{print $NF}'` and where from Time.done, file.done, Date.done files were coming ?

Comment: `unzip -l archive.zip` lists all the files inside archive.zip and their properties.`unzip -l $file | awk '/.xml$/{print $NF}` keeps only the lines that terminates with .xml and prints last column from those lines.

Answer (score 1):

One way (Not tested)

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.zip" -type f)
do
    [ -f "${file}.done" ] || continue
    unzip $file -d /home/b/file_input
    for file1 in $(unzip -l $file | awk '/.xml$/{print $NF}')
    do
       cp /home/b/file_input/$file1 /home/b/file_input/${file1}.done
    done
    rm $file    
done
```

The check is done for .done file using the -f condition. If it is false meaning the .done file is not present, the loop will continue to pick the next file. cp command will create a .done file from the .zip file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. cp $file ${file}.done, will create a .zip.done right as u have added on $file which has the zip? the .done should be added on the extracted .xml file like .xml.done. Correct me if I misunderstood, I am new to Unix.

Comment: As I told above, it's not adding xml.done file in output folder. Also how can I delete the .zip.done file also ? will it be rm ${file}.done

Comment: Thanks Guru, I tried but it fails in cp command, looks liek it's not able to find the extarcted file : cp: cannot stat `FIXML-363_CME_EOD-20121129.xml': No such file or directory"  This file is there in my test zip file.